# Ajuda com footer desalinhado em flexbox

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de uma ajuda com o meu `footer` , que está ficando totalmente desalinhado, já tentei um `clear: both` , mas sem sucesso, gostaria de uma ajuda pra corrigir este erro. o código original do footer é este:
https://codepen.io/x-gyba/pen/pEmyRk

e o meu projeto atual é este:
https://codepen.io/x-gyba/pen/pNmbEe

Vejam que ele fica totalmente deformado, onde pode estar o erro?

Comment: primeiro, a tag "<p> está com max-width:700px"(pegando do escopo global), por isso o copyright não está alinhado no center corretamente

Comment: Veja aí: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrNWaq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, sua tag: `<a href="#contato"> </a>` está faltando um `>`

Segundo, sua classe `.footer-infos` tem que estar assim:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```